# Creation of user specific folder upon user registration in Laravel 5.8.37

Tags: laravel

I am just learning and exploring laravel from the basics.

The situation is this. What I have in mind is, creating a specific folder for users upon registration of their account. As I've searched through out the net, I have seen some people were successful with the process, using makedirectory etc... Copying their codes I came up with this one

registerController.php

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'middle_name' => $data['middle_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'contact_no' => $data['contact_no'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $path = public_path(). '/users/' . $user->id.;
    File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);

    return $user;

}
```

I was hoping that upon user registration I could see something like this

project_name>storage>app>public>users>10001>

throughout the registration process I didnt received any error code, but whats disappointing is, the expected folder werent there.

Need your advice.... Thanks in advance

Comment: You have `return User::create([...]);`... The code below `return` will not execute... That should probably be `$user = User::create([...]);`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Nothing after `return` will be executed. `$user` is not set. `$path = public_path(). '/users/' . $user->id.;` will throw a `PHP parse error` because of that last `.`

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies,  I have fixed the issue, also thank you Tim Lewis for the correction It works like a charm =)

Answer (score 0):

u can try this one

```
$dirpath = public_path(). '/users/' . $user->id;
if(!is_dir($dirpath))
{
   mkdir($dirpath, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies,  I have fixed the issue, also thank you Tim Lewis for the correction It works like a charm =)